# How do I get the properties of an object using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I know I can do this

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in myobject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (property.DeclaringType.ToString() == myobject.GetType().ToString())
    {
         // only have my object properties here
         // and not parent of my object properties
    }
}
```

But how can I **just** get the properties of myobject and not those of the parent as well?
ie not have to do that extra if statement.

edited for answer, (Thanks @Greg Beech)
This worked:-

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in 
             myobject.GetType().GetProperties
                 (BindingFlags.Public | 
                  BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                  BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    // only properties of my object not parent of myobject
}
```

I also found this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` and pass that to `GetProperties` (you'll probably want to combine it with `BindingFlags.Public` and `BindingFlags.Instance` at least).