# Test whether a property is declared in the derived class

Tags: .net, reflection

I have two classes

```
public class A
{
  public int BaseA
{get;set;}
}

public Class B: A
{
 public int BaseB
{get;set;}
}
```

I can get the Properties for the Class B by using typeof(B).GetProperties(). However, this would include both the BaseA and BaseB properties. But I want to obtain the BaseB property only.

Note: I found the solution, it's

```
  B boy = new B();
            var pList = boy.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                  BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                  BindingFlags.Instance);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, pList.Length);
```

A similar solution [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245401/how-do-i-get-the-properties-of-an-object-using-reflection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at using BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly when calling Type.GetProperties().